# drools dsl adding expression to last pattern with '-' not working

Tags: drools, dsl

I have been working with drools rules for a while and just recently started on a dsl to make the rule authoring easier for end users. While I have been able to get a simple dsl defined and correctly compiling into drl as expected, i cannot get the dsl feature of 'adding constraints to previous expression' to work. 
I am even trying the simplest of examples from the drools dsl guide and this will not compile the Conditions i have defined beginning with '-' into the previous expression. I keep getting a 'mismatched input 'price' in rule "Rule1Sample_0" error on compiling it.
as i said I have this working for straightforward Condition expressions and Consequence expressions. but adding contraints following the docs is just not working at all.
I am using drools version 7.0.0.Final, is this something thats not supported until a later version?

in the simple example i am testing, my dsl file just contains:

```
[condition][]There is a {ShoppingCart} that=${ShoppingCart!lc} : ${ShoppingCart!ucfirst}()
[condition][]- total price is greater than 1000 =totalPrice > 1000

[consequence]Update {ShoppingCart}=System.out.println("{ShoppingCart}" + " test")
```

Here is the Condition

```
"There is a ShoppingCart that total price is greater than 1000"
```

and Action which i am specifying for the when and then part of my template:

```
"Action" "Update ShoppingCart"
```

Here is the compiled drl before I pass it to the DrlParser:

```
    rule "Test1"
      dialect "mvel"
      when
         "There is a ShoppingCart that total price is greater than 1000"
      then
        "Update ShoppingCart"
    end
```

This is what expandedDrl string contains after above code snippet runs:

```
package com.sample.test

rule "Test1"
  dialect "mvel"
  when
     $shoppingcart : $Shoppingcart() total price is greater than 1000
  then
    System.out.println("ShoppingCart" + " test")
end
```

And here is the generated drl for this when i parse it using the DRLParser:

(code snippet here, some omitted)

```
DrlParser parser = new DrlParser();
        DefaultExpanderResolver resolver = new DefaultExpanderResolver(new StringReader(dsl));
        String expandedDrl = parser.getExpandedDRL(dslr, resolver);
```

This is what expandedDrl string contains after above code snippet runs:

```
package com.sample.test

rule "Test1"
  dialect "mvel"
  when
     $shoppingcart : $Shoppingcart() total price is greater than 1000
  then
    System.out.println("ShoppingCart" + " test")
end
```

And the compiler error i see in the console:

```
[[13,43]: [ERR 102] Line 13:43 mismatched input 'price' in rule "Test1"  ....
```

Comment: could anyone point me to a github example for this feature? where i could actually see a working code sample to confirm this does actually work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Could you try condition

```
There is a ShoppingCart that
- total price is greater than 1000
```

---

Could you try following dsl

```
... business definitions
[when]complex condition = (simple condition 
                           or another condition)
[when]simple condition = (total price is not 0)
[when]another condition = (total price greater than 10)

... field definitions
[when]total price = totalPrice

... consequences I advise to wrap in java util class each as a static method to write java code in java code
[consequence]Update {ShoppingCart}=System.out.println("{ShoppingCart}" + " test")

... tech dsl at the bottom

[when]There (is( an?)?|are) {entityType}s?( that)? = ${entityType}: {entityType}()
[when](is\s+)?not less than(\s+an?)? = >=
[when](is\s+)?less than(\s+an?)? = <
[when](is\s+)?not greater than(\s+an?)? = <=
[when](is\s+)?greater than(\s+an?)? = >
[when]((is|do(es)?)\s+)?not equals?(\s+to)? = !=
[when](is\s+)?equals?(\s+to)? = ==
[when]is not(\s+an?)? = !=
[when]is(\s+an?)? = ==
[when]like(\s+an?)? = matches
[when]{prefix}?\s*(?<![\w])and(?![\w])\s*{suffix}? = {prefix} && {suffix}
[when]{prefix}?\s*(?<![\w])or(?![\w])\s*{suffix}? = {prefix} || {suffix}
[when]{prefix}?\s*(?<![\w])not(?! (in|matches|contains|memberOf|soundslike|str))(\s+an?)?(?![\w])\s*\({suffix}? = {prefix} false == (true && {suffix}
[when]{prefix}?\s*(?<![\w])not(?! (in|matches|contains|memberOf|soundslike|str))(\s+an?)?(?![\w])\s*{suffix}? = {prefix} !{suffix}
[when](?<![^\(,])\s*- =
```

this should be able to process rules like

```
There is a ShoppingCart that
- total price is greater than 1000
- not complex condition
```

If you want to reuse conditions in other conditions you want them to be atomic. Good rule of the thumb to embrace RHS with braces () not to break atomicy of the record

---

**test**

```
@DroolsSession({ "classpath:/test.rdslr", "classpath:/business.dsl", "classpath:/keywords.dsl" })
public class PlaygroundTest {

    @Rule
    public DroolsAssert drools = new DroolsAssert();

    @Test
    public void testIt() {
        drools.insertAndFire(new ShoppingCart(BigDecimal.valueOf(1000.5)));
        drools.insertAndFire(new ShoppingCart(BigDecimal.valueOf(999)));
    }
}
```

domain

```
public class ShoppingCart {
    public BigDecimal totalPrice;

    public ShoppingCart(BigDecimal totalPrice) {
        this.totalPrice = totalPrice; 
    }
}
```

rdslr

```
rule Test1
    when
        There is a ShoppingCart that 
        - total price is greater than 1000
    then
        print eligible price
end

rule Test2
    when
        There is a ShoppingCart that 
        - worth a discount
    then
        print eligible price
end
```

business.dsl

```
[when]worth a discount = 
    (total price is not less than 500
    and not over limit
    or total price is greater than 5000)
// stupid condition just for demonstration
[when]over limit = ((total price + total price * 0.05) > total price + 50)
[when]total price = totalPrice

[then]print eligible price = System.out.println($ShoppingCart.totalPrice);
```

keywords.dsl

```
[when]There (is( an?)?|are) {entityType}s?( that)? = ${entityType}: {entityType}()
[when](is )?not within\s*\({tail}?= not in ({tail}
[when](is )?within\s*\({tail}?= in ({tail}
[when](is )?not one of\s*\({tail}?= not in ({tail}
[when](is )?one of\s*\({tail}?= in ({tail}
[when]ignore case '{tail}?= '(?i){tail}
[when]{param:[$\w\.!'\[\]]+} as {param2:[$\w\.!'\[\]]+}=(({param2}) {param})
[when](is\s+)?not less than(\s+an?)? = >=
[when](is\s+)?less than(\s+an?)? = <
[when](is\s+)?not greater than(\s+an?)? = <=
[when](is\s+)?greater than(\s+an?)? = >
[when]((is|do(es)?)\s+)?not equals?(\s+to)? = !=
[when](is\s+)?equals?(\s+to)? = ==
[when]is not(\s+an?)? = !=
[when]is(\s+an?)? = ==
[when]like(\s+an?)? = matches
[when]{prefix}?\s*(?<![\w])and(?![\w])\s*{suffix}? = {prefix} && {suffix}
[when]{prefix}?\s*(?<![\w])or(?![\w])\s*{suffix}? = {prefix} || {suffix}
[when]{prefix}?\s*(?<![\w])not(?! (in|matches|contains|memberOf|soundslike|str))(\s+an?)?(?![\w])\s*\({suffix}? = {prefix} false == (true && {suffix}
[when]{prefix}?\s*(?<![\w])not(?! (in|matches|contains|memberOf|soundslike|str))(\s+an?)?(?![\w])\s*{suffix}? = {prefix} !{suffix}
[when](?<![^\(,])\s*- =
```

test output

```
00:00:00 --> inserted: ShoppingCart[totalPrice=1000.5]
00:00:00 --> fireAllRules
00:00:00 <-- 'Test1' has been activated by the tuple [ShoppingCart]
1000.5
00:00:00 --> inserted: ShoppingCart[totalPrice=999]
00:00:00 --> fireAllRules
00:00:00 <-- 'Test2' has been activated by the tuple [ShoppingCart]
999
```

Comment: I tried this, but get same result  mismatched input 'price' in rule

Comment: thanks, i ill try this approach. so do you mean the dash does not work as expected for adding constraints to a fact?

Comment: It works, dash means 'use is as sub-constraint for recent Type(here)'. But it causes limitation when you want complex regex replacements happen several times. Usually you do as DSL processor can repeatedly replace snippets in predictable order (from the top to the bottom of single file, multiple files are loaded in unpredictable order) and step-by-step resolve your very complex statements to valid logical structures. So when you start your statement with dash, you can use it only as 'a whole line statement', it will look ugly in '- simple condition or - another condition' definition.

Comment: I tried your dsl from above, but i dont see the constraints appear within the () for the entity they apply to? e.g. i see $shoppingCart: ShoppingCart() totalPrice < 1000  rather than $shoppingCart: ShoppingCart(totalPrice < 1000) which is what i need.  how can i use this approach for contraints on the entity? for my use case, i will have combinations of contraints, reusing same conditional more than once with 'ands' and 'ors'. e,g, i will need something like - $shoppingCart: ShoppingCart(totalPrice < 1000 && totalPrice > 500 || totalPrice == 350)   sorry for poor example i am using here!

Comment: It should definitely go as inner constraint. Something else here causing the issue.

Comment: the code I gave you was working production code, there were really complicated structures which were resolved correctly as inner constraints even for several outer conditions

Comment: any line which starts with - will go as inner constraint for the last Type() braces.

Comment: do you have multiple dsl files?

Comment: The parser will pick up a line beginning with "-" and add it as a constraint to the preceding pattern, inserting a comma when it is required. [source](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_jboss_bpm_suite/6.2/html/development_guide/sect-domain_specific_languages_dsls)

Comment: I am using only 1 dsl file in my testcase, i have others defined but do not load them. i removed them in case they were interferring but no difference. so wahatever is causing the issue with '-' is also causing the issue with your production version of dsl outlined above. neither approach is adding constraints to the last ()

Comment: do you see anything wrong with the code call to the DrlParser?  the 2 params i pass in here, are 1) a (compiled from template) drl, which has the condition and action text to be formatted by dsl, and the dsl file.

Comment: I have never seen manual initialization of the parser, I thought you've copied working example somewhere. I'm loading dsl just like any other resources into the session, [example](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3165020/448078)

Comment: I just tried using the approach defined in your link above (adding them to the session as Resources  rather than parser and i get same result, the knowledgeBuilder instance reports the same error:   Line 8:42 mismatched input 'price' in rule "Test1"].  what version of drools can you confirm this works on? i was using v7 but just tried v6.3.0 and same issue with this version

Comment: I'm on another project now, production is running on v6... but there should be no issues with v7

Comment: 'mismatched input price' means that it somehow replaced [- total ]price... you should have some other definitions with [total] and it was resolved before [total price]

Comment: BTW, write a [test](https://github.com/droolsassert/droolsassert/) for it. Limit number of files you are loading to few necessary ones.

Comment: edited my post, added working example, please confirm it works for you

Comment: thank you for this! finally i see where i was going wrong and as i thought it was something so simple i had not seen. That the rule description (dslr condition) needed to include the '-' too. I had not gotten that from the docs. I see now that you suggested this in your first answer but i misread your comment and thought you were referring to the dsl condition definition and not the condition in the dslr itself. So the condition needs to be defined with each constraint on a new line (didnt work when i just had condition on 1 line) preceded with a '-' for this to work. again thank you!